# init.d script does not run start on boot but starts manually (Raspbian)

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, systemd, init.d

Whenever the system starts, the *zfs-import* init script does not run:

```
root@kapnet:# /etc/init.d/zfs-import status
● zfs-import.service - LSB: Import ZFS pools
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/zfs-import; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
```

There is nothing in /var/log/syslog like it did not even try

If I start it manually, it runs fine:

```
root@kapnet:# /etc/init.d/zfs-import start
[ ok ] Starting zfs-import (via systemctl): zfs-import.service.

root@kapnet:# /etc/init.d/zfs-import status
● zfs-import.service - LSB: Import ZFS pools
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/zfs-import; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2019-06-16 08:49:06 EEST; 12s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1463 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/zfs-import start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      CPU: 416ms

Jun 16 08:48:59 kapnet systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Import ZFS pools...
Jun 16 08:49:00 kapnet zfs-import[1463]: Warning: You're not running 64bit. Currently native zfs in
Jun 16 08:49:00 kapnet zfs-import[1463]:          Linux is only supported and tested on 64bit.
Jun 16 08:49:05 kapnet zfs-import[1463]: Importing ZFS pool(s) .
Jun 16 08:49:06 kapnet systemd[1]: Started LSB: Import ZFS pools.
```

also it seems to be enabled:

```
root@kapnet:~# systemctl enable zfs-import
zfs-import.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable zfs-import
insserv: Service mtab has to be enabled to start service zfs-import
insserv: Service mtab has to be enabled to start service zfs-import

root@kapnet:~# systemctl is-enabled zfs-import
zfs-import.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install is-enabled zfs-import
enabled
```

Why it doesn't run on boot?

EDIT: I installed ZFS using [this guide](https://gist.github.com/mohakshah/b203d33a235307c40065bdc43e287547).

Answer (score 2):

As you are told by **systemd**:

> zfs-import.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install.

Old style **SysV** init system is deprecated and not used anymore. For compatibility it is only emulated by systemd but there are limitations. Look at [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/).

If you encounter problems with SysV emulation then the first step should be to use native services from systemd. It doesn't make sense to fiddle with the emulation. So first have a look for a native service for your script. You could ask at github where you got *this guide*. If they don't like to help, you can try to make a unit file to start the program (not the init.d script, that starts the program). You can look into the init.d script what program is started and then start it with a systemd unit file. Because lack of information about this I cannot help much more. But to give an idea here is a very simple template of a unit file. Create a new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo --full --force edit my-zfs-import.service  # zfs-imort.service already exists
```

In the empty editor you insert statements, save them and quit the editor.

```
[Unit]
Description=Very simple template for zfs import
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/zfs-import

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable the new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable my-zfs-import.service
```

Certainly there are additional conditions needed to get your program to run. You will find many examples for a unit file here on this site. If you encounter problems with your try, just make a new question about it.